# Remove/Filter array of objects with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

```js
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
  var what, a = arguments,
    L = a.length,
    ax;
  while (L && this.length) {
    what = a[--L];
    while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
      this.splice(ax, 1);
    }
  }
  return this;
};

var items = [{
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}, {
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}, {
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}, {
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}]

var datesToRemove = [{
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-06 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-06 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}];
console.log("Before: " + items.length)
for (var i = 0; i < datesToRemove.length; i++) {
  items.remove(moment(datesToRemove[i].start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
}
console.log("After: " + items.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.js"></script>
```

I want to remove the objects from one array using another array as a reference. Both arrays only contain the object below. All the corresponding objects in `datesToRemove` should be removed in the `items` array.  Properties I was thinking I could use are `start`. Unfortunately there is no `Id`

This is my code so far:

The Object looks like this:

```
   var item = {
                            title: 'Bokningsbar',
                            start: moment(datesValue + " " + hourValue.start),
                            end: moment(datesValue + " " + hourValue.end),
                            allDay: false
                        };
```

Prototype.remove

```
       Array.prototype.remove = function () {
        var what, a = arguments,
            L = a.length,
            ax;
        while (L && this.length) {
            what = a[--L];
            while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                this.splice(ax, 1);
            }
        }
        return this;
    };
```

use case:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < datesToRemove.length; i++) {
                            items.remove(moment(datesToRemove[i].start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
                        }
```

With this setup I get the error `Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. And all athe obects are removed. Here is also a not working example. But maybe it illustrates what I want. If anybody got a better suggestion on how to remove the objects feel free to suggest it.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to extend the native `Array` prototype to get this done. There are a few methods for dealing with `Array` manipulation that are already available natively to JavaScript and can tackle your problem. More so, following along with using a custom `Array` method in conjunction with a for loop for a solution could very easily produce unexpected/unintended negative side effects that limit how well this solution could scale for future use within your application. The most obvious potential pitfall is mutating your original data structures, drastically limiting reusability and making it difficult to easily and accurately debug issues caused further down the application stack. These native `Array` methods will keep your original data structures intact, creating shallow copies of the `Array` instances during manipulation and returning them as your final result. As an additional bonus, these methods can be chained together in as many ways and as many times as you may need.

- `.map()`
- `.filter()`
- `.reduce()`

Another `Array` manipulation method commonly utilized is `.forEach()`. The `.forEach()` method removes the hassle of having to write and maintain messy `for` loops; making the overall codebase much easier to read and much easier to follow logically. However, `.forEach()`, unlike the 3 previously listed `Array` manipulation methods, does NOT protect against mutating any original data structures used. It can be included in the chain you may create using the other `Array` methods mentioned. However, once called, `.forEach()` breaks the ability to chain your methods any further.

`.map()`, `.filter()`, and `.reduce()` provide a pure, functional approach to the iteration and manipulation of an `Array`. While all 3 methods still offer a means by which to loop over an `Array`, each method offers it's own unique functionality and purpose for manipulation. Understanding the distinct use of each method first is crucial to understanding when and how to chain them together effectively.

**`.MAP()`**

- `.map()` : Similar to `.forEach()`, this method loops over each item in the given `Array`. As the loop iterates over each item's index, the individual items are run against a provided method for manipulation. The end result is a new `Array` with every item being the product of the transformation function provided during the loop. The important note to remember using `.map()` is that the new `Array` that is returned after the loop completes will ALWAYS be the same length as the original `Array` used. This makes `.map()` an excellent choice when you need to return a new `Array` with item values that reflect a desired transformation when compared against the original `Array`, and all of it's item values.

**Example:**

```
const originalArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const incrementedArr = 
  originalArr.map(
    (n,i,arr) => {
      return n + 4
    }
  )

console.log(originalArr)     // console output => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(incrementedArr)  // console output => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In the example above, the `incrementedArr`  constant could be rewritten in a much more concise way. For the purpose of answering your question thoroughly, I wrote it verbosely to illustrate an important note to always keep in mind. `.map()`, `.filter()`, and `.reduce()` each offer three arguments by default. The 3 arguments for `.map()` and `.filter()` are the same. They are:

1. **item**

   > The individual item value found at each index of the loop's iteration
2. **index**

   > The index value for each item found during the iteration of the loop
3. **array**

   > Provides a reference to the original array being used by the loop

That said, here's a more concise illustration of `.map()` from the example above:

```
const originalArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const incrementedArr = originalArr.map(n => n + 4)

console.log(originalArr)     // console output => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(incrementedArr)  // console output => [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**`.FILTER()`**

- `.filter()` : Again, like `.forEach()`, this method loops over each item in the given `Array`. As it does, it compares the value of each item in the `Array` against a provided conditional check, returning either `true` or `false` for each item at each index within the `Array`. The final output will be an `Array` of item's whose values all returned as the same `Boolean`, either as `true` or `false` depending on the conditional check provided. This makes `.filter()` the perfect choice for when you need to return a new `Array` that may need to be a different length compared to the original `Array` provided. In other words, the new `Array` returned is a direct reflection of the conditional check used to filter out item values no longer needed in the original `Array`.

**Example:**

```
const originalArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const noEvenNumbersArr = originalArr.filter(n => n%2)

console.log(originalArr)     // console output => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(noEvenNumbersArr)  // console output => [1, 3, 5]
```

**.REDUCE()**

The `.reduce()` method, like the other `Array` methods mentioned, loops through all of it's items in a given `Array`. It's argument parameters are different than `.map()` and `.filter()`. Also, while `.map()` and `.filter()` ALWAYS return an `Array`, `.reduce()` offers the ability to return and `Object` instead. `.reduce()` takes a bit more time to properly explain than the other two methods discussed. Also, using what we've discussed using `.map()` and `.filter()`, a solution can be formed to properly address the problem originally posed.

**THE SOULTION**

```
// The Array "items" contains values that need to be removed.

const items = [
  { title: 'Bokningsbar',
    start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
    end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
    allDay: false },

  { title: 'Bokningsbar',
    start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
    end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
    allDay: false },

  { title: 'Bokningsbar',
    start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
    end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
    allDay: false }, 

  { title: 'Bokningsbar',
    start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
    end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
    allDay: false }
]


// The Array "datesToRemove" contains values that match what needs
// to be removed from the"items" Array

const datesToRemove = [
  { title: 'Bokningsbar',
    start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
    end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
    allDay: false }
]
```

The `.filter()` method can handle everything needed for a solution to the problem... Almost. The problem now revolves around 2 things specifically,
 1. Not filtering an Array of items against another Array of items. Instead, you're trying to filter an Array of OBJECTS against another Array of OBJECTS. If that is the intention here, you can modify the following to check for native `Object` methods (and iterators) such as `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`.

```
  const mergeUniqueMatches = (catArr) => catArr.filter((elem, pos, arr) => arr.indexOf(elem) == pos)
  const mergedArr = mergeUniqueMatches(items.concat(datesToRemove))
```

Logging `mergedArr` to the console gives shows a new `Array`. The original data is still perfectly untouched. Again, shallow copies are what we are working with here.

Now the trick is to "Dedupe" the `mergedArr`. Lucky for us, ES6/7 makes this a piece of cake. Try:

```
const dedupedArr = [...new Set(mergedArr)]
```

Moving any further though requires some clarification on your end. You could make this much easier for yourself by providing a key (like generated a uuid) any time and `items` object is added to the `Array`. Then after that item moves to the `datesToRemove` `Array`, all you need to do is a `.filter()` off the instance ID key (uuid) to remove the right items safely, and without worrying about mutating any data along the way.

I'll leave you with these two finally alternatives,

```
  const destructingOptionWithES6 = {
    ...items,
    ...datesToRemove
  }

  const ideallyAllYouShouldHaveToDoIsThisFunction = items.filter(val => !datesToRemove.includes(val))
```

Comment: First of all. Thank you for this long an descriptive answer. I find your answer very enlightening.  I finally found what was causing all the error in my code. It was a user created error. The date format I was expecting from SharePoint had an error in it. I implemented a date format check and everything started to work as intended. I changed some of my iterations to `map()` thanks to your post thats why I will mark it as my answer.

Comment: No worries. Glad this helped get you to the answer. Kudos on using `.map()` in your quick refactor. Keeping data immutable is always a sound choice.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, `remove` expects the (exact) same element and is usually not working well on complex elements.

I suggest to use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var items = [{
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}, {
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}, {
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-05 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-05 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}, {
  title: 'Bokningsbar to remove',
  start: moment("2018-04-06 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-06 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}]

var datesToRemove = [{
  title: 'Bokningsbar',
  start: moment("2018-04-06 06:00"),
  end: moment("2018-04-06 07:00"),
  allDay: false
}];

for (var i = 0; i < datesToRemove.length; i++) {
  var toRemove = datesToRemove[i];
  items = items.filter(function(element) {
    return element.start.valueOf() != toRemove.start.valueOf();
  });
}

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and suggesting a solution to my problem. In the end, my errors were caused by the user. I implemented a check for the data I was expecting and everything started to work as intended. Thank you again!